# How do I use an std::fstream from within a block?

Tags: c++, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++, ifstream

I'm having trouble trying to use an `ifstream` from within a block. (This is part of a larger, complex project, so I whipped up a quick little source file with just the relevant parts.)

```
// foo.cpp, in its entirety:

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Block.h>

int main() {
    __block std::ifstream file("/tmp/bar") ;
    // ^ tried this with and without the __block
    void (^block)() = ^{
        file.rdbuf() ;
        file.close() ;
        file.open("/tmp/bar") ;
    } ;
    block() ;
}
```

If I declare the `ifstream` with `__block`, I get:

```
foo.cpp:6:24: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
      'std::ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>')
        __block std::ifstream file("/tmp/bar") ;
                              ^~~~
```

If I declare it without `__block`, I get:

```
foo.cpp:8:3: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
      'const std::ifstream' (aka 'const basic_ifstream<char>')
                file.rdbuf() ;
                ^~~~
                // rdbuf() and (presumably) other const functions

foo.cpp:9:3: error: member function 'close' not viable: 'this' argument has
      type 'const std::ifstream' (aka 'const basic_ifstream<char>'), but
      function is not marked const
                file.close() ;
                ^~~~
                // open(), close(), and (presumably) other non-const functions
```

What's the proper way to use `fstream`s inside of blocks?

Comment: I don't know what an objective-c  block is, but could you use lambdas instead?

Comment: @Pubby I don't know what a lambda is, so I'm using Objective-C-style blocks instead. XD

Comment: This is `C++/CLI` rather than `C++`, right?

Comment: It's, ummm…a command-line program written in `C++`? So, yes, `C++`, but also `C++/CLI`? Unless the `./CLI` is something else.

Comment: <Block.h> is not part of standard C++

Comment: It's not standard, no. But I can still use it, can't I? After all, `third-party library name here` isn't part of standard C++.

Comment: `<Block.h>` is straight C, I believe, to be compatible with Objective-C and C++. (Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong; I'm really just guessing.)

Comment: @us2012 no, it uses [Blocks (C language extension)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension))

Comment: @KarthikT Nonstandard language _extension_, okay. Is it bad to use it or something, then? o.o

Comment: @BlacklightShining you are welcome to use if you are ok with non portable code. The confusion here is that you do not explain that in your question, so we are left guessing what it is, until we look at the tags..

Comment: @BlacklightShining but yes, as pubby says, lamdas are the new standard way to do what the extension tries to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25110/discussion-between-blacklight-shining-and-karthik-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Block Implementation Specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html#c-support)

> It is an error if a stack based C++ object is used within a block if it does not have a copy constructor.

Which is the first error - [`ifstream` blocks copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream). `__block` requires copy.

As the quote says, one option is to declare ifstream on heap(`new`/`delete`).. but that is messy.

The rest of the errors are simple const correctness errors. Not declaring `__block` imports the objects as a const copy, which is the first of the two errors, and it cannot be used to call non const functions like `close`.

Try to switch to [lamda expressions from `C++11`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/1561811) and see if they alleviate these issues.

Comment: not declaring `__block` copies the variable when the block is created

Comment: @newacct fixed it to a const copy